# Is it bad idea to extend Zend_View and register like front controller plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, view

I just ask, is it bad idea to extend Zend_View and register like Front Controller plugin after router is ready, because i need, $request to get active module name to show Zend_View where are my templates ?

```
public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

    $view = new View($config, $request);  

    $viewHelper = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view);

    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewHelper);    

}
```

And after that i get $request->getModuleName(); and make the my ScriptPaths

I have tried this method 
`$viewHelper->setViewScriptPathSpec(':controller/:action.:suffix')`
But can't work.

Comment: Why do you need the module name for your script paths? Can't this be achieved through layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to extend View.
You could create controller action plugin which will assign request to View initialized by application resource plugin Zend_Application_Resource_View. But assign only what is necessary (module name) and not full request - for security.